# Exit while in the process of execution if the debugger takes a long time to execute something

Tags: c#, debugging

I want to exit the program during the process of execution if the debugger takes a long time to execute something even if that process is not completed. I have been trying this:

```
var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
dssPut_Command("Compile " + SystemID + "abc.dss");
if (watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds > msLimit)
{watch.Stop();
return false;
}
```

I want to exit immediately during the execution if it takes more time. So lets say it is taking long time to execute the dssPut_command part, exit before the execution is completed.

Comment: You can create **Task** with method you need execute and combine it with **Task.Delay** by using **Task.WhenAny** method.

Comment: So, in my case how would my implementation be using Task.Delay

Comment: I think you can try something like this